# Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element' - Bing Maps veapidelay.js

Tags: javascript, xml, bing

I am using BING maps with customized infobox with htmlcontent property. when i try to execute the function i am getting the below error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The provided markup is invalid XML, and therefore cannot be inserted into an XML document.

My code looks like this

```
function createPushpins(pPins) {

    var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
    var pinLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();

    var infoboxOptions = { width: 254, htmlContent: "<div id='customBoxInfo'><div class='topimage'></div><div class='middleimage'></div><div class='bottomimage'></div></div>" };
    pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), infoboxOptions);
infoboxLayer.push(pinInfobox);
    }
```

This is happening when i click the push pin.

The error is throwing in "veapidelay.js:3" script reference file from "https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&s=1".